# Returning to previous activity in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have two activities: `MainActivity` and `Activity2`:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;        
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
        button.Text = "Button created at " + time.ToString();
        button.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

and:

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity2")]
public class Activity2 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity2);

        Button button_close = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_close);
       
        button_close.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }
}
```

Clicking on `button` opens Activity2 and hides MainActivity. `button_close` closes Activity2 and opens a new instance of MainActivity. But I do not want a new instance to be created. **How can I revive exactly the original previously-created instance of `MainActivity` and return to it after Activity2 is closed?**

Here, `button.Text` shows whether a new instance of `MainActivity` is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `Finish()` on Activity2, it will return to the previous.

If you want to pass some kind of result, you can use [StartActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and in [OnActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) get the resulting data.

Comment: Using Finish solves the problem. But my main problem is for Notifications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784717

Comment: I know this is old, but how would this be adapted if I want to send data from 1 activity in project 1 to return to a main activity in another project, all in the same solution? Dependancy injection?

Comment: If you want to do it cross-platform, don't use intents to pass around state, but rather use some kind of shared state mechanism, it could be a singleton in your IoC.